# How to convert an latex image based image into dowloadable url

Tags: asp.net

I have an url "https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csmall%20%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7Bs%7D" in which when it is given as input to WebClient in asp.net application, the image has to get downloaded.

Used [this website](http://latex2png.com/) to convert, get images from url.

**test.aspx.cs**

```
string url = "https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csmall%20%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7Bs%7D";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string path = Server.MapPath("Images"); // Create a folder named 'Images' in your root directory
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(url);
webClient.DownloadFile(url, path + "\\" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this. Download the image and serve it directly as download on your site. But you can save it to disk with just one line of code.

```
protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csmall%20%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7Bs%7D";
    string fileName = "MyImage.png";

    //create a new webclient
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        //download the external file
        byte[] bin = client.DownloadData(url);

        //save it do disk
        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/") + fileName, bin.ToArray());

        //or let your user download it directly
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```